# Diagonalisation of a ghost Lagrangian

Tags: gravity, lagrangian-formalism, ghosts

I have a ghost Lagrangian of the form

$\mathcal{L}= \bar{c}M_{11}c +  \bar{c}M_{12}b +  \bar{b}M_{21}c +  \bar{b}M_{22}b$

where $c,b$ are the ghosts and $\bar{c}, \bar{b}$ the anti ghost fields, $M_{ij}$ are matrix elements in the form of covariant derivatives/ Laplace operator, which is not important here, in a certain tetrad formulation of gravity. I want to diagonalize this Lagrangian and eliminate the mixed terms of $b$ and $c$, using field redefinitions. I have tried field redefinitions of the form

$\tilde{b}= b + M_{22}^{-1}M_{12}c, \tilde{c}= c + M_{11}^{-1}M_{21}b$,

but it does not diagonalize the above Lagrangian. What kind of field redefinitions can be used to diagonalize the Lagrangian such that it contains only $\bar{c}-c$ and $\bar{b}-b$ terms?

Comment: More precisely, what is $M$ in terms of covariant derivatives/ Laplace operator?

Comment: $M_{11}=-4\nabla_{\mu}\nabla^{\mu} ,
M_{22}=2\nabla_{\nu}\nabla^{\nu} ,  M_{12}=4\nabla_{\gamma} , M_{21}=-2(\nabla_{\delta}F^{\delta}+ F^{\delta} \nabla_{\delta}) $

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: No this is not from any reference. This is something worked out as a part of exercise.

Comment: What kind of field redefinitions will render a diagonal matrix M is what I am asking. I find the task of finding some matrix U such that UMU^T is diagonal, not a feasible thing to do here. If that is possible, please suggest.